# How to mock MapStruct nested mapper in JUnit5

Tags: java, junit5, mapstruct

I have been searching a solution for about a day now. I still cannot produce a working example.

My problem is simple. I have a mapper uses another mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {RoleMapper.class})
public interface UserMapper {

    /**
     * Converts User DTO to User JPA Entity
     * @Mapping annotation is used to convert fields with different names
     * @param dto
     * @return
     */
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "identityNo", source = "dto.userIdentity"),
            @Mapping(target = "role", source = "dto.roleDTO")
    })
    User dtoToEntity(UserDTO dto);

    /**
     * Converts User JPA Entity to User DTO
     * @Mapping annotation is used to convert fields with different names
     * @param entity
     * @return
     */
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "userIdentity", source = "entity.identityNo"),
            @Mapping(target = "roleDTO", source = "entity.role")
    })
    UserDTO entityToDto(User entity);

}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface RoleMapper {

    Role roleDtoToEntity(RoleDTO dto);
    RoleDTO roleEntityToDto(Role entity);
}
```

My test class which tests mapper works as it should:

```
class UserMapperTest {

    private UserMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    @Test
    void dtoToEntity() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("john");
        user.setSurname("doe");
        user.setIdentityNo("11111111111");
        user.setRole(new Role("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        UserDTO dto = mapper.entityToDto(user);

        Assertions.assertEquals(user.getName(), dto.getName());
        Assertions.assertEquals(user.getSurname(), dto.getSurname());
        Assertions.assertEquals(user.getIdentityNo(), dto.getUserIdentity());
        Assertions.assertEquals(user.getRole().getName(), dto.getRoleDTO().getName());
    }
}
```

However, NullPointerException is thrown on the line where roleMapper is called in automatically generated impl class **UserMapperImpl**:

[image: img]

it comes to my basic problem, *how to mock or autowire a nested mapper class?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nested mapper is null, because Spring context is not loaded. Due to this, @Autowired is not working.

Solution is to inject nested mappers via ReflectionTestUtils.

```
@InjectMocks
private UserMapper mapper = UserMapperImpl.INSTANCE;

@Before
public void init() {
    RoleMapper roleMapper = Mappers.getMapper(RoleMapper.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mapper, "roleMapper", roleMapper);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Jakub Słowikowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13227834/jakub-s%c5%82owikowski) mentioned, but a bit more fancy:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private MyApi myApi;

    @Spy
    private MyMapper myMapper = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this option better, looks cleaner and we don't have to declare reflection in our tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your app's ecosystem, but if you use spring boot, you can mark test class UserMapperTest as `@SpringBootTest` and autowire your mapper as a regular bean

```
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper mapper;
```

Comment: That is sometimes an option, but brings a large performance penalty (setting up full spring context takes time), so it's best to avoid where possible

Comment: Yeah, one way to improve it can be setting lazy context initialization for such tests